# Using JSON content in client-side js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have a nodejs file that reads my JSON file within a function inside a post route. I have declared a variable inside this function which returns an array that I would like to access in my client-side javascript file. Is there any way I could make this variable a global variable that I can access within the client-side Javascript file or alternatively, can I read the JSON file in the client-side Javascript file? Either will do.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

*app.js*

```
app.post("/addtask", function(req, res) {


    fs.readFile('results.json', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data)

    var newTask = req.body.newtask;
    var newDate = req.body.newdate;

    if (newTask!=''){

        json.JSONtask.push([newDate,newTask]);

        task = json['JSONtask']  //VARIABLE THAT I WOULD LIKE TO ACCESS IN CLIENT SIDE

        fs.writeFile("results.json", JSON.stringify(json),function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });

    } 
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

*cleint-side js (an example showing where I would like to access the variable again)*

*(function is activated by a button click).*

```
function overlayOn(id) {
    console.log('id:',id)
    var para = document.createElement("P");
    para.innerHTML = task[id][1];   //VARIABLE ACCESSED AGAIN
    document.getElementById("text").appendChild(para)
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
  }
```

**NOTE:** `json['JSONtask']` gives an array with nested arrays.

Comment: if you don't want to redirect  replace it with `res.send(task);`

Comment: to give you a complete  answer add full client html you use

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan I do still want it to redirect.

Comment: Well... you can't declare a variable on your server's code and use it directly in a browser on a completely different physical machine... that's not how server-clients work. You need to _call_ your server from the browser, and then the server must _send_ the data back with like `res.json(myJson)`